# How to create a layered PSD file from using Gimp command line?

Tags: gimp, psd, gimpfu

I need to create a layered PSD file from a list of PNG images using the GIMP command line, in which each PNG image is one layer of a generated PSD file. I found one [git](https://gist.github.com/endavid/fceea065e586052de944ffc57014692c) related to this. It runs successfully without any error, but it didn't create a PSD file at a given location. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! You should probably include precisely how you run this code.  Also, I think you’d probably get an answer faster on a specialized gimp forum.

Comment: What is your OS? The "Usage exemple" is for a Linux/OSX shell, it won't work in Windows.

Comment: I am using Windows 10. I added that script in the 'C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\share\gimp\2.0\scripts' path as suggested in git. Is it possible to run that on windows?